# How do I forward propagate in just subset of Dataframe columns with inplace=True?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I want to fill missing values with fillna() and "inplace=True".
How do I forward propagate values in just two columns of a Dataframe that has more than two columns?
Thanks

Comment: i just realized you want `fillna(inplace=True)` on a column subset specifically with `method='ffill'`. i don't think that's possible

Comment: `fillna()` with specific values (not `ffill`) on specific columns can be done with a dictionary: `df.fillna({'a': 0, 'd': 0}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to forward propagate a column subset with `method='ffill'` and `inplace=True`.

You'll have to use assignment, e.g. for columns `A` and `D`:

```py
df[['A','D']] = df[['A','D']].fillna(method='ffill')
```